# Read content of all files in S3 path in one go with boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Using boto3, I can read the content of a file stored in S3 via

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object(bucket_name, path).get()['Body'].read()
```

I have multiple files in the same path ("directory") and I'd like to read them all building a global data variable storing their comprehensive content (say a dictionary or list).

Is there a way to accomplish this from boto without having to read them one by one and concatenate the bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the S3 API that supports reading multiple objects in a single API call.  You could spin up multiple threads with each retrieving an object to get better throughput.